# Change variables in ChangeListener?

Tags: java, swing, changelistener

I am making a matching card program and I want to make sure the user only selects two card. So I have made Changelisteners and inside those changelisteners I would like to have an integer that would increase when there is a change in the state of the button. I have tried to use int, but it gave me the error where it says to use a final or effectively final. Is there some way that I can use an int inside of the changelistener method.

Here is an example:

```
  card1Button.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
      //int increases here

        }
    });
```

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, you could use two `ButtonGroup`s instead, it would ensure that only one button from each group can be selected

Answer (score 0):

You could change the scope of your variable

```
    public class CardGame {
      private int x;

      public CardGame() {
          card1Button.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
              public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                  x++;
              }
          });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why? How is it going to solve the use of the OP attempting to reference a local value from within the context that the listener is added to the button?

Comment: " I would like to have an integer that would increase when there is a change in the state of the button."  I though that it was global. OP didn't said it was a local variable.

Comment: *" but it gave me the error where it says to use a final or effectively final"*

Comment: Oh I see. It would only show that error if the variable was local.

Answer (score 0):

You have two basic choices to solve the immediate issue

## You could...

Make the counter an instance field

```
public class MyAwesomeCardGame extends ... {
    private int counter;
    //...

    public MyAwesomeCardGame() {
        //...
        card1Button.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                counter++;
            }
        });
   }
}
```

## You could...

Make the `counter` a instance of field of the anonymous class

```
public class MyAwesomeCardGame extends ... {
    //...

    public MyAwesomeCardGame() {
        //...
        card1Button.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            private int counter;
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                counter++;
            }
        });
   }
}
```

## Alternatively

Depending on what you're doing, you could use two `ButtonGroup`s instead, it would ensure that only one button from each group can be selected at a time

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that shows how you can do this when using a JCheckBox:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CheckBoxGroup
{
    private Set<GroupButtonModel> models = new HashSet<GroupButtonModel>();
    private int groupSize;

    public CheckBoxGroup(int groupSize)
    {
        this.groupSize = groupSize;
    }

    public void register(JCheckBox checkBox)
    {
        ButtonModel groupModel = new GroupButtonModel();
        groupModel.setSelected ( checkBox.getModel().isSelected() );
        checkBox.setModel( groupModel );
    }


    private class GroupButtonModel extends JToggleButton.ToggleButtonModel
    {
        @Override
        public void setSelected(boolean selected)
        {
            if (!selected)
            {
                models.remove( this );
                super.setSelected( selected );
                return;
            }

            //  Check number of currently selected check boxes

            if (models.size() == groupSize)
            {
                System.out.println("Only " + groupSize + " items can be selected");
            }
            else
            {
                models.add( this );
                super.setSelected( selected );
            }

        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        CheckBoxGroup group = new CheckBoxGroup(3);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox( String.valueOf(i) );
            panel.add( checkBox );
            group.register( checkBox );
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Check Box Group");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( panel );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It adds a custom model to the component to check the number of currently selected components before allowing you to select another component.

It will also work for a JToggleButton. Just change the register(...) method to register toggle buttons.